# Including submodule's jar/classes into other submodule's jar using Maven

Tags: maven, jar, runtime, classpath, multi-module

I have a multi-module maven project, with a parent/child structure given below:

| parent                  -> pom pack
| -- submoduleAppletUtils -> jar pack
| -- submoduleAppletA     -> jar pack
| -- submoduleAppletB     -> jar pack
...
| -- submoduleAppletN     -> jar pack

Each applet jar is dependant on submoduleAppletUtils classes. 
I am using maven-jar-plugin given below to include manifest Class-Path entry for each these jars pom files. Upon building each jar, submoduleAppletUtils related jar/classes are not being included in any of the generated jars. Wondering how to achieve it, so as to make them available at run time.

-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven assembly plugin and add the AppletUtils as dependency in the assembly descriptor.